# How to keep animation playing when moving from scene to scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have an indestructible canvas with an animator attached to it it plays certain animations when moving from Home to level and from level to home However |
Home - > level , playes fine | 
Level - > home, playes fine |
but when Home - > level for the second time it gets stuck on the home animation without playing the home - > level animation